# Oracle SQL: Slicing big results into chunks

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a large table (too large, to query at one time). I need a efficient strategy to "slice" the results into chunks - allowing incremental updates and avoiding timeouts.

I guess there is a smarter solution than

```
SELECT
    tbl1.ID,
    tbl2.*
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM FOOUSER.TABLE1 ORDER BY ID) tbl1
JOIN 
    FOOUSER.TABLE2 ON tbl1.ID = tbl2.ID2
WHERE 
    ID > :LASTMAXVALUE
    AND ROWNUM <= 1000
ORDER BY 
    tbl1.ID;
```

.. with `:LASTMAXVALUE` being the maximum value of `ID` from the last query, and `ROWNUM <= 1000` giving chunks of 1000 rows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `(SELECT * FROM FOOUSER.TABLE1 ORDER BY ID FETCH FIRST 1000 ROWS ONLY) tbl1` may perhaps work.

Comment: Thanks, but will `FETCH FIRST`work on the second query - say i want the next 1000 items starting with `ID > 1000` ?

Comment: `...ORDER BY ID OFFSET 1000 FETCH FIRST 1000 ROWS ONLY...`

Comment: @jarlh iirc, this idiom is not available for 11g.

Comment: If your actual goal is to perform updates on the result set, perhaps the best approach would be not to update. In some cases where the update affects enough of the table it is more helpful to insert the data fresh in a new table and rename it (or partition if it applies). Bear in mind you'd have to consider your application availability requirements and other factors.

Comment: I only want to get data out of the database (`SELECT`), no `UPDATE` needed.

Comment: Please provide table schema. Is there no natural grouping of the data available?